# Using character in the grep function in R

Tags: r

I have 600 characters **n** I would like to apply **grep** function using all of them to the **b**

**n**

```
[1] "KO_2"    "KO_12"   "WT_14"   "KO_16"   "WT_21"   "WT_35"   "KO_41"   "KO_44"   "KO_45"   "KO_47"   "KO_50"   "KO_57" 
[13] "WT_59"   "KO_60"   "KO_64"   "KO_65"   "KO_69"   "KO_70"   "KO_72"   "KO_81"   "KO_87"   "KO_88"   "WT_95"   "WT_105"
```

**b**

```
[1] "KO_2"    "WT_3"    "WT_4"    "KO_6"    "WT_7"    "WT_8"    "WT_9"    "KO_10"   "KO_11"   "KO_12"   "WT_13"   "WT_14"  
  [13] "WT_15"   "KO_16"   "WT_17"   "KO_18"   "WT_19"   "WT_20"   "WT_21"   "WT_22"   "WT_24"   "WT_25"   "WT_26"   "WT_27"  
  [25] "WT_28"   "WT_29"   "WT_30"   "KO_31"   "KO_32"   "KO_33"   "KO_34"   "WT_35"   "KO_37"   "KO_38"   "WT_39"   "KO_40"  
  [37] "KO_41"   "KO_42"   "KO_44"   "KO_45"   "WT_46"   "KO_47"   "KO_48"   "WT_49"   "KO_50"   "KO_51"   "KO_52"   "WT_53"  
  [49] "WT_54"   "KO_55"   "KO_56"   "KO_57"   "WT_59"   "KO_60"   "KO_61"   "WT_62"   "KO_63"   "KO_64"   "KO_65"   "WT_66"
```

Comment: Could you be more clear in your request? What is "n" and what would you like to achieve?

Comment: n are my patterns which I want to check whether they are present within b. I want to get indexes of this patterns - meaning where they are positioned in b.

Comment: Do you need `which(b %in% n)`  because I don't see this as a pattern match but an exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n <- c(letters[15:20], '1', '2', '3')
b <- letters

unlist(sapply(n, function(l) which(b == l)))

#  o  p  q  r  s  t 
# 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

You can use `which`, it tells you the index of where a test is true. Now you just have to apply this to your vector of letters to test.

**EDIT :**

As mentioned by @Chris, if you have multiple matches, you have to be careful. In this scenario, you can remove the `unlist()` and the result will be a list of vectors holding the indices of matched elements. 
Note that elements with no match are also in this list, but their corresponding vector is empty (`integer(0)`)

```
n <- c("KO_2","KO_12","WT_14","KO_16","WT_21")
b <- c("KO_2","WT_14","KO_12","WT_14","KO_44","KO_45","KO_47","WT_35","KO_41")
sapply(n, function(l) which(b == l))
# $KO_2
# [1] 1
# 
# $KO_12
# [1] 3
# 
# $WT_14
# [1] 2 4
# 
# $KO_16
# integer(0)
# 
# $WT_21
# integer(0)
```

Comment: And do you know how to get the indexes only without the "letters"?

Comment: This is "the indexes only", the letters are just the names of the vector. If you really want to get rid of them, you can do `names(result) <- NULL`

Comment: @RoB's solution is nice and clever but care is needed with the output: if applied to my data the solution changes the matched values if they are matched more than once: `unlist(sapply(n, function(l) which(b == l)))
  KO_2  KO_12 WT_141 WT_142 
     1      3      2      4`; cf. `WT_141` and `WT_142`

Answer (score 1):

To find out where what you call the "patterns" `n`are positioned in `b`, you can use `match`:

```
n <- c("KO_2","KO_12","WT_14","KO_16","WT_21")

b <- c("KO_2","WT_14","KO_12","WT_14","KO_44","KO_45","KO_47","WT_35","KO_41")

match(b,n)
[1]  1  3  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA
```

This tells you that pattern 1 `KO_2` occupies position 1 in `b`, pattern 3 `WT_14`has positions 2 and 4 in `b`, pattern 2 `KO_12` occurs in position 3 in `b`, while none of the other patterns in `n` have matches in `b`.